# Как работать только с последней из повторяющихся записей из цикла?

Tags: php

Из json файла я считываю много записей в которых повторяется код фирмы. Мне важна только последняя из повторных запись, что бы внести ее в базу данных. Как это сделать?

```
c_code | emplyees
12345  | 2 
12345  | 1
12345  | 3 
54321  | 5
54321  | 6
98765  | 2
85632  | 1
85632  | 2
```

Вот пример данных. Мне нужно занести в базу 12345  | 3, 54321  | 6, 98765  | 2 , 85632  | 2

```
$reader = new JsonReader();
        $reader->open($filename);

        while ($reader->read()) {
            if ($reader->name() === "jarCode") {
                $jarCode = $reader->value();
            }

            if ($reader->name() === "numInsured" && $jarCode!='') {
                $numInsured = $reader->value();

            $set_emp_code = $crm_conn->query("UPDATE accounts SET employees_no = '{$numInsured}' WHERE id_c = '{$jarCode}'");

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: а ем был плох `json_decode`, файл большой слишком,  или чего?

Comment: `array_column($items, 'employes', 'c_code')` даст вам массив. где ключами будут коды фирмы, а значениями последне вхождение.

Comment: да, файл 400мб, 350000 записей

Comment: если у вас данные друг за другом идут всегда, то читайте эти пары значений. Когда код меняется то делайте запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ключи идут подряд, то нужно просто сохранять текущее значение. А когда оно меняется - записывать его в базу

```php
$reader = new JsonReader();
$reader->open($filename);
$jarCode = null;
$numInsured = null;
$curCode = null;
$curInsured = null;

while ($reader->read()) {
  switch ($reader->name())
    case "jarCode": $jarCode = $reader->value(); break;
    case "numInsured": $numInsured = $reader->value(); break;
  }
  if ($jarCode !== null && $numInsured !== null) {
    if ($jarCode !== $curCode) {
      if ($curCode !== null) {
        $set_emp_code = $crm_conn - > query("UPDATE accounts SET employees_no = '{$curInsured}' WHERE id_c = '{$curCode}'");
      }
      $curCode = $jarCode;
    }
    $curInsured = $numInsured;
    $numInsured = null;
    $jarCode = null;
  }
}
if ($curCode !== null) {
    $set_emp_code = $crm_conn - > query("UPDATE accounts SET employees_no = '{$curInsured}' WHERE id_c = '{$curCode}'");
}
```

Параметризированные запросы добавить по вкусу

Comment: спасибо огромное за такой ответ! :)